# instantaneous backup to external drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup

I have an external hard drive, and I want to use it as a backup drive. So my question is "how to update a backup folder when the original folder gets updated?", I'm talking about an instant backup. As I can remember Linus sebastian made a server like an instant backup server and I want this to be the same via external drive. Is there a software that I should download or do I need to make the program in a .bat format.

Comment: See this (not free)....https://www.techsoftpl.com/backup/

Comment: Free....http://mirrorfolders.com/en/index.html

Comment: You can use https://syncthing.net/ if you put that external HD on another PC.

Comment: What's your OS?